# [BIBLIOGRAPHY][RUSSIAN] How can I change the references style?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

everybody.
I'm working with my university's standart. It seems to much like russian GOST, but there are some diffences which I could't solve in my own.
The bibliography style that I'm using:  `\bibliographystyle{ugost2008}`

The reference style for a book should be the next.

```
<Reference number> <Principal author (Last name, initials)><Title> [Текст]: <Additional information> / <All authors (Initials, family)>.- M.: <Publisher>,<Year>.-<Number of pages>c.
```

An example:

> 1 Katz, J. Low-speed aerodynamics: from wing theory to panel methods
>   [Текст] 2-е изд. / J. Katz., A. Plotkin. – М.: Cambridge University
>   Press, 2001. – 613 с.

The reference style for an article should be the next.

```
<Reference number> <Principal author (Last name, initials)><Title> [Текст] / <All authors (Initials, family)> // <Journal>.-<City>, <Year>.-<Volume>,<Number>.-C.<Pages>.
```

An example:

> 18 Österheld C.M. Preliminary Design of a Blended Wing Body
>   Configuration using the Design Tool PrADO [Текст] / C.M. Österheld, W.
>   Heinze, P. Horst // Proceedings der CEAS Conference on
>   Multidisciplinary Aircraft Design and Optimisation.- Köln, 2001. –
>   C.1-10.

Comment: @dwolfeu Yes, thank you for the help!

Comment: You have a much better chance of getting help if you can share a short example document with us that cites a few example entries for the types you want to change. For the slightly less careful reader like me it would also help if you could *explicitly* state the required changes, not just the desired outcome.